# Cannot remove powered by opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new with opencart. I've been trying to remove the powered by Opencart for the past few days.

I've tried changing : admin/language/en-gb/common/footer.php

and changed the last part and now it looks like this unfortunately nothing has changed:

```
<?php
// Text
$_['text_information']  = 'Information';
$_['text_service']      = 'Customer Service';
$_['text_extra']        = 'Extras';
$_['text_contact']      = 'Contact Us';
$_['text_return']       = 'Returns';
$_['text_sitemap']      = 'Site Map';
$_['text_manufacturer'] = 'Brands';
$_['text_voucher']      = 'Gift Certificates';
$_['text_affiliate']    = 'Affiliates';
$_['text_special']      = 'Specials';
$_['text_account']      = 'My Account';
$_['text_order']        = 'Order History';
$_['text_wishlist']     = 'Wish List';
$_['text_newsletter']   = 'Newsletter';
$_['text_powered']      = '%s &copy; %s';
```

Comment: i just googled [how to remove the powered by Opencart](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=how+to+remove+the+powered+by+Opencart&oq=how+to+remove+the+powered+by+Opencart&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.2127j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) & found no. of solutions.

Comment: I have tried all the steps but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

you go to admin\view\template\common\footer.tpl and delete

Comment: Deleted this file but still visible. :/

Answer (score 0):

Go to for remove the front end powered from website

1.catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl.

2.Comment the part or delete.

3.Then Powered by removed.

Comment: That part is deleted also but still visible :/

Comment: You used another theme?